# How to disable Chrome's developer tools hotkeys?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

For example, if I switch to Chrome's window using QuickSilver and press CMD+O, if the developer tools windows is focused, it will open the "Source" tag on it:

[aff http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/oe.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/oe.png)

Instead of focusing the URL bar on top, which is what it does normally. This is really annoying because I have to click on the screen to unfocus the developer tools bar all the time. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

⌘O is assigned to File > Open File... for me. Have you assigned a custom shortcut for `View Source` in the keyboard preference pane? Or could the shortcut be changed by some extension?

This should disable the shortcuts in the developer menu:

`defaults write com.google.Chrome NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"View Source"="\0";"Developer Tools"="\0";"JavaScript Console"="\0";}'`

You have to quit and reopen Chrome to apply changes. You can undo it with `defaults delete com.google.Chrome NSUserKeyEquivalents`.